# Some dash bootstrap component themes such as MORPH & QUARTZ are not working

Tags: python, bootstrap-4

To add styling to a python dash app you can include

`app = dash.Dash(external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP])` and then change the theme name to get a different style.

However it seems that some themes work such as

`dbc.themes.MINTY` or `dbc.themes.CYBORG`

But others such as `dbc.themes.MORPH` or `dbc.themes.QUARTZ` do not.

Is there a difference in how they should be called or have they been deprecated?